Posgtesql ODBC incorrectly loaded char(1) despite of setting client encoding to utf-8
I tried to select data with Cyrillic encoding by linux odbc postgresql driver in UTF8.
I set client_encoding to UTF8.
The data of column with length > 1 (for example, varchar(10) = 'инсерт' - in Cyrillic) is loaded correctly in UTF-8 encoding.
But the data of column with length = 1 (for example, varchar(1), symbol = 'и' - in Cyrillic ) is loaded incorrectly.
I expected following data with UTF8 encoding with length =2: 0xd0, 0xb8. But I got data with length =1 : 0xd0.
If I performed following sql query:
SELECT convert_to( 'и',  'UTF8')

I got result with length = 2 :  0xd0, 0xb8.
Do you know this case is error on odbc driver? Should I use some parameter for odbc postgresql driver on linux?
Thank you.

Is it the client that calls ODBC or the ODBC driver that chops off the second byte?

ODBC driver, I believe. I use otl library in C++, that uses ODBC driver.

Try to narrow down where the problem happens. For example, write C code that accesses the ODBC driver directly, not through a library. Then you can tell where the problem is. Alternatively, use a debugger.

@LaurenzAlbe, you right, the library otl cuts data. It cuts data based on function SQLDescribeCol(). SQLDescribeCol returns column length in symbols count= 1. Do you know  SQLDescribeCol  can return length in bytes?

I don't know, but I doubt it. PostgreSQL doesn't know the length in bytes. Try to get the library fixed.
